# OBIEE - Conditional Formatting of Gauge

Tags: conditional-formatting, obiee, gauge

I am helping build an analysis which uses a series of gauges to provide a visual indication of how full certain quotas are.

For a few of these, the values are actually over-budget but the gauges are meaningless to look at as the needle has disappeared. Example - Maud's budget is 4 but is over-budget (actual value is 7). Aside from the fact I've added a label to indicate this, the gauge is pretty meaningless:

[image]

Ideally, I'd love to be able to introduce conditional formatting so that if things are over budget it stands out - for example:

[image]

I can't see a way of doing this - as conditional formatting seems to be limited to columns which affects how data is displayed in a pivot table ...

Is this type of conditional formatting for a gauge even do-able?!

Comment: No, but you could probably do it with D3js or other similar libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, the charting engine doesn't support this out-of-the-box

Comment: Thanks Christian. That was my gut feeling. Does your response mean that it would be do-able if we delved into the xml? Or do we just forget about it?